# create PDF file in JS

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, backbone.js, pdf-generation

I am developing a web application using client side MVC. The technology stack is Backbone JS, HTML5 and Spring at the Server side.

I have a requirement where I do some data manipulation at the client side using Javascript by using JSON files as the data payload kept on the web server directly. This is a high traffic part of the app and I don't want to hit my app server for such siple data manipulations.

Now on the same module - I have a requirement where I need to generate a PDF file which effectively contains a static template and then I need to fill the template using effectively the same data that I already have at client side. I need to generate the PDF and let the user download it.

Any idea how can I acheive it completely at the client side in a clean and robust way.

Comment: i think you also should take in consideration browser support for older browsers so a backend solution could be better

Comment: I think it is important to mention that this site shall also be used on mobile devices.

Comment: If it was me, I would try to do server-side PDF generation, which I could use a tool like wkhtmltopdf or princexml to generate a PDF with consistent results, regardless of the client browser. However, if you must do it client side, you might consider DocRaptor (https://docraptor.com/), which provides HTML-to-PDF as a web service. Presumably the client could post HTML and CSS to DocRaptor, and then retrieve the PDF. I haven't used DocRaptor, but I know it's based on PrinceXML.

Comment: I don't agree that the question is too broad.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand is you have an html template that you want to fill with certain data and then render it as a pdf?

For client side, have tried looking at something like jsPdf (http://parall.ax/products/jspdf)? The html renderer is still in early stages but it seems to work decently.

As Bogdan pointed out, a backend solution is also possible. You could look at pd4ml (http://pd4ml.com/) or even call into something like pandoc (http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) or even phantomjs (http://phantomjs.org/) to perform the conversion and then pass the generated pdf back to the client.

If it is not an html template, I am sure a number of the above solution should work regardless.